# link a movieClip to a class programmatically?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I want to ask if there is a way to link a movieClip with a class programmatically, without going to the properties menu and checking "export to actionScript" (in flash pro). I know that you can just use addChild or use other work-arounds, but is there a specific method that does this thing.

For example: movieClip.link(class)

Comment: pretty sure you can't do this.

Comment: too bad...it would make things alot more clearer to read and easier to manage. As I said I have ways to work around this and everything seems to work fine, but this would make things just a little bit clearer

Comment: What clarity would that bring? A `movieClip` is just an instance of a class `MovieClip`. You can always extend it although it is a dynamic class so there's little sense in doing that. What are you trying to achieve by "linking" a class to an instance of `MovieClip`?

Comment: I made a program in flash pro cs5.5 some time ago, and there some movieClips were linked to classes that implemented their functionality. I am writing a similar program on flash builder and there am getting my movieClips as external swfs files, my plan was to load those mcs from the swfs and just link them to their classes similar to what i did in flash pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe this is what you want:
[Using Flash Symbols with ActionScript in Flex](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/03/using_flash_sym.html)

Comment: actually, come to think of it, its kinda correct. =D thanks =D